# Uniform distribution

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, uniform-distribution

You arrive at a bus stop at 10 O'clock, knowing that the bus will arrive at some time uniformly distributed between $10$ and $10:30$. what is the probability that you wait longer than $10$ minutes? if at $10:15$ the bus has not arrived what is the probability that you will have to wait at least an additional $10$ minutes?

Im confused as to if im supposed to take $P( 5<x<10)$ assuming bus arrives at $10:15$, or $P(15<x<20)$ assuming bus arrives at $10:30$. Is this even right? please help!

Comment: It seems like you weren't through typing before you posted. Why don't you go ahead and finish giving us your thoughts on the problem, so we can better help you?

Comment: Unless it is inside MathJax delimiters, $<$ registers as the start of an HTML tag and "eats" the rest of the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $B$ be the time (in minutes) elapsed since 10 o'clock.  Then $B$ is uniformly distribute on the *interval* $[0,30]$ with density $\dfrac{1}{30}$.

The probability that the waiting time is longer than 10 minutes is $P(B ??)$.

> $$P(B>10) = \frac{30-10}{30-0} = \frac23.$$

If the bus hasn't arrived at 10:15 (we're given a condition, so think of the definition of conditional probability), the probability that one will have to wait for at least an additional 10 minutes is $P(B?? | B??)$.

> $$P(B>25|B>15) = \frac{P(B>25,B>15)}{P(B>15)} = \frac{P(B>25)}{P(B>15)} = \frac{\frac16}{\frac12} = \frac13$$